# why cQueue insert is not working in omnet?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have created a few cQueues as follows:

```
cQueue *mybuffs[4];
```

in my header file. And created the objects as:

```
void mybuffs::initialize() {
    // TODO - Generated method body

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        mybuffs[i] = new cQueue(NULL,NULL);
    }

    cMessage *timer = new cMessage("mytimer");
    scheduleAt(simTime() + exponential(1.0), timer);
}
```

then when i try to insert msg objects to it using

```
mybuffs[1]->insert(msg);
```

the cQueue shows empty in the simulation. Not a single msg object gets enqueued in this cQueue.

What could be the possible reason for it?

Comment: mybuffs[i] = new cQueue(NULL,NULL); this line creates the object

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I somehow didn't see that line at all.

Comment: @user3243499: Which method do you use to check whether `mubuff[1]` is empty? After `mybuffs[1]->insert(msg);` the method `mybuffs[1]->getLength()` returns 1.

Comment: The code works fine. It was just a logical error. I had this logic inside an if-else block, and I overlooked this if(condition). So, this block of code was not even getting executed, and so the cQueue never got enqueued.